# MongoDB find and update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose in my node application.
I want to fetch all the records with status='Submitted' and return those records to frontend and behind the scenes it should update the status of those records from submitted to 'Sent'.
I want to make only one request from frontend to backend and should complete both the tasks. 1. Fetching and returning the data, 2. Update those records' status

```
{
   id:1
   status:'Submitted'
},
{
   id:2
   status:'Submitted'
},
{
   id:3
   status:'Sent'
}
```

So records with id 1,2 should be sent to frontend and status of both the records should be updated to 'Sent'.

Data to Send to frontend:

```
{
   id:1
   status:'Submitted'
},
{
   id:2
   status:'Submitted'
}
```

Data in db after sending data:

```
{
   id:1
   status:'Sent'
},
{
   id:2
   status:'Sent'
},
{
   id:3
   status:'Sent'
}
```

Comment: can you share your schema pls.

Comment: I have just 2 fields which are mentioned above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems

1. Update all matching a condition
2. Return the updated documents

Unfortunately, both are not possible in single query.

`updateMany` can be used to update all the documents matching a condition. But it doesn't return the updated documents.

On the other hand, you have `findOneAndModify` which updates and returns. But only one documents as name says.

You can choose as per your requirement.

I suggest you to `find` first then use it in the frontend then send a `updateMany` to the server.